# SQL Server database access EC2

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have 4 servers in an EC2 (amazon cloud services), one of them contains SQL Server 2008.

I want to restrict the access to the database to be just from the other servers I have running.

I wanted to do that using the EC2 security groups but all my instances use the same security groups and as far as i know once the instance is created the security group is constant.

I know there is something that is relevant to the "Protocols for DBNAME" in the SQL Server network configuration (in the SQL Server Configuration Manager) but I have no idea how to use it.

Right now it defines that IPAll TCP Port is 1433 ... and the rest (from what I checked) is not relevant ...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define inbound rules recursively.  If your security group is named "default" and has an id of "sg-123456789", you can add a rule to the security group that says "let sg-123456788 access port x to y". You can make changes to your security group while it is in use.  Of course, all this can be done through the management console.

Comment: god bless you :) i used what you say and defined access inside the group for all ports and outside just to the application required ports without the mssql ports...